# Opening New Window in Jframe

Tags: java, jframe

When you click the button "Search" it should open up the class MISControlPanel.java, but instead it opens up a window like you see in the picture. It shouldn't be blank like that. 
Any ideas why the class is coming up blank? I think it has something to do with initializing "newWindow" to null(otherwise it threw this error: "The local variable newWindow may not have been initialized") so I'm not sure. [image]

relevant snippet from code below

```
 MISControlPanel newWindow = null;
                    try {
                        newWindow = new MISControlPanel();
                    } catch (IOException e3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e3.printStackTrace();
                    }
                        newWindow.setVisible(true);
```

---

Full class code

---

```
      import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.naming.InvalidNameException;
import javax.naming.ldap.LdapName;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.naming.ldap.LdapName;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Inet4Address;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class MISSearch {

    JFrame frame;
    static JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;
    JLabel selectedComputerFromAD = new JLabel("testing");
    String sCurrentLine = null;
    String CN = null;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MISSearch window = new MISSearch();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     * 
     * @wbp.parser.entryPoint
     */
    public MISSearch() throws IOException {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     */

    private void initialize() throws IOException {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        frame.getContentPane().setForeground(Color.RED);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 394, 111);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frame.setTitle("MIS Control Panel");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\anoc5f\\Desktop\\Output.txt");
        File tempFile = new File("myTempFile.txt");
        JButton searchComputerButton = new JButton("Search");
        searchComputerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                 MISControlPanel newWindow = null;
                try {
                    newWindow = new MISControlPanel();
                } catch (IOException e3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e3.printStackTrace();
                }
                    newWindow.setVisible(true);

                    try {
                        new test();
                    } catch (IOException e2) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e2.printStackTrace();
                    }

                String line;
                BufferedWriter bw = null;
                BufferedWriter writer = null;
                try {
                    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }


                String s = null;

                Process p = null;
                /*
                 * try { // p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                 * "cmd /c start c:\\computerQuery.bat computerName"); } catch
                 * (IOException e1) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 * e1.printStackTrace(); }
                 */
                try {

                    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\computerQuery.bat");

                } catch (IOException e1) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    e1.printStackTrace();

                }
                StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p
                        .getInputStream()));

                try {

                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                        System.out.println(line);

                        // textArea.append(line);

                        String dn = "CN=FDCD111304,OU=Workstations,OU=SIM,OU=Accounts,DC=FL,DC=NET";
                        LdapName ldapName = new LdapName(dn);
                        String commonName = (String) ldapName.getRdn(
                                ldapName.size() - 1).getValue();

                    }
                    ComputerQuery.sendParam();

                } catch (IOException e1) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    e1.printStackTrace();

                } catch (InvalidNameException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } finally

                {
                    try {
                        fw.close();

                    }

                    catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                try {

                    in.close();

                } catch (IOException e1) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    e1.printStackTrace();

                }

                ComputerQuery.sendParam();
        /*
                   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                          testLabel.setText(CN);
                        }
                      });
            */
            }
        });


        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "resultofbatch.txt"))) {

            final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("CN=([^,]+).*");
            try {
                while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    String[] tokens = PATTERN.split(","); // This will return
                                                            // you a array,
                                                            // containing the
                                                            // string array
                                                            // splitted by what
                                                            // you write inside
                                                            // it.
                    // should be in your case the split, since they are
                    // seperated by ","
                    // System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                    CN = sCurrentLine.split("CN=", -1)[1].split(",", -1)[0];

                    System.out.println(CN);

                }

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        // SwingUtilities.invokeLater(updateCN());
        searchComputerButton.setBounds(269, 17, 89, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(searchComputerButton);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(164, 17, 95, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblComputerName = new JLabel("Computer Name:");
        lblComputerName.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        lblComputerName.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        lblComputerName.setBounds(41, 11, 124, 29);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblComputerName);
        java.net.InetAddress localMachine = null;
        try {
            localMachine = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

        JLabel label = null;
        JLabel lblOpid = new JLabel("Computer by OPID:");
        lblOpid.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        lblOpid.setBounds(23, 46, 137, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblOpid);

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setBounds(164, 48, 95, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField_1);
        textField_1.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("Search");
        btnNewButton_2.setBounds(269, 47, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_2);

    }
    public void setVisible(boolean visible){
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    private void threadStart() {
          SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                        }
          });
        }

}
```

Comment: I'm not getting a NullPointerException. I'm not getting any error, it's just not opening up the class properly. It's coming up blank. I was forced to initialize "newWindow" though, which I initialized to null

Comment: The `setVisible()` method should be added to `MISControlPanel` class, not `MISSearch`. I assume these are seperate classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because you use `newWindow.setVisible(true);` but your `MISControlPanel` don't extend `Window` class to inherit `setVisible()` method, but has field `JFrame`, and you need to set it visible separatly. Try to add this method to `MISControlPanel`:

```
public void setVisible(boolean visible){
    frame.setVisible(visible);
}
```

Comment: I added the method, but I think it might be trying to extend window still because the MISControlPanel class is still coming up blank. I added the full class code above. The setVisible method added is at the bottom of the class. See code above

Comment: @user6680 But now there is no MISControlPanel class. So how it works without it? Did you just change names?

Comment: The MISControlPanel Class is still there. It's located in the default package with the MISSearch class above.

Comment: I didn't change any of the class names

Comment: @user6680 so did you add setVisible() to MISControlPanel? because with this component you have a problem

Comment: I see what you mean. I added the method to the MISSearch class. When I moved it to the MISControlPanel class, the class opened with no issues. I've been stuck on this for awhile. Thanks for all your help! I